# "npm isntall" command exists

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, package-managers

When you type an illegal `npm` command, you are getting a user-friendly error message stating which commands are legal to use:

```
$ npm illegal

Usage: npm <command>

where <command> is one of:
    add-user, adduser, apihelp, author, bin, bugs, c, cache,
    completion, config, ddp, dedupe, deprecate, docs, edit,
    explore, faq, find, find-dupes, get, help, help-search,
    home, i, info, init, install, isntall, issues, la, link,
    list, ll, ln, login, ls, outdated, owner, pack, prefix,
    prune, publish, r, rb, rebuild, remove, repo, restart, rm,
    root, run-script, s, se, search, set, show, shrinkwrap,
    star, stars, start, stop, submodule, tag, test, tst, un,
    uninstall, unlink, unpublish, unstar, up, update, v,
    version, view, whoami
```

As you may notice, among others there is *`isntall` command*.

What is the point of this command? If this was created to handle typos, then why doesn't it have a special handling for `intall`, `insatll` etc? Besides, `uninstall` doesn't have a corresponding `unisntall` option.

(Using npm `1.3.22` version).

---

The reason I ask is that I'm a bit surprised and confused about how the typo is handled. For example, `git` compares the command you've entered and suggests the closest commands it has available:

```
$ git stats
git: 'stats' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.

Did you mean this?
    status
```

Also, [`pip` Python package manager](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip) has a similar functionality built-in:

```
$ pip isntall
ERROR: unknown command "isntall" - maybe you meant "install"
```

<sup>FYI, [under-the-hood](https://github.com/pypa/pip/blob/5defca2e25d71656509d93f77e0098c28ecf7801/pip/commands/__init__.py#L63-L74) it uses [`difflib.get_close_matches()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html#difflib.get_close_matches) function.</sup>

Comment: It's to remind you that npm isntall that.

Comment: OP, you should google your questions. This was my first result on the keyword 'isntall', from npm's github page. https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/2933

Comment: Fun fact: the newest version of npm still accepts `isntall` as an alias, but it doesn't show it on that list anymore as to not confuse people. Personally I think having such an alias is just plain silly, but judging by the Github issue, they don't want any more feedback on that.

Comment: @alecxe: I guess with your rep you already know that "*What do you think?*"-questions are offtopic? You might bring up such things in chat.

Comment: this totally weirded me out today

Comment: this probably saved millions of hours worldwide, and then wasted it back by people starting to research that anomaly and writing comments like this one

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I was the original "raiser" of the connected issue on Github, and those were the first days of contributing to OSS software... I thought it was just a typo, and maybe a pull request would solve it. But I was blessed with some good sense to first **[raise an issue (#2933)](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/2933)** to find out if they were looking for contribution on that front...

As it turned out, it unravelled a whole discussion around the issue, which was good to see.

The *raison d'être* of the `isntall` command is because the `npm` maintainers believe that it saves them time — and thus, by extension — several other developers. As has been discussed in the linked issue, this was a contentious decision, and several people have suggested more interesting methods for resolving typos such as using the levenshtein distance calculation of the illegal command from valid npm commands (https://www.npmjs.org/package/levenshtein).

At any rate, I presume if you do implement one of those algos and contribute to the npm project, it would be a nice addition to this awesome library...

Answer (score 1):

Because there's no way to handle every single possible typo, without breaking other stuff. Init could possibly be a typo of install.

Could do levenshtein distance from your input or something but introduces unnecessary complexity.

Comment: `isntall` is actually hardcoded. It's such a common mistake that it became part of npm. it's not calculated based on small mistake